# Vue CLI - vue add pwa causes TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tapAsync') error

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-pwa

I'm building a web app with Vue 3 and after executing `vue add pwa` I get the following error:
`./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-pwa/lib/HtmlPwaPlugin.js:62`
`compilation.hooks.htmlWebpackPluginBeforeHtmlProcessing.tapAsync(ID, (data, cb) => {`
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tapAsync')`

How should I resolve this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one had me swimming for a bit as well.

upgrade the pwa plugin.

```
vue upgrade pwa
```

For me, I was at version 4.5.15 and the latest was 5.0.1

Comment: Yes that's what I did as well.